# Sketching a tri signal with horizontal shift

Tags: discrete-signals, visualization

I'm unsure how to sketch a tri signal with horizontal shift.

Eg , let's say we want to sketch tri((t-4)/4). Can I reduce it to tri( (t/4) - 1 )? This would mean sketching a tri(t/4) signal and shifting it to the right by 1. Or should it be a tri(t/4) signal shifted to the right by 4?

I've found out on wikipedia that the rect signal is defined as rect((X-Y)/T) where you shift the center of the signal by varying Y. But I'm not sure if sketching tri applies the same concept.

Comment: Using tri(t) as a reference, plot tri( (t-4)/4 ) by plugging in points for t and you have your answer.

Comment: You stretch by a factor of 4 and then shift right by 4.

Answer (score 1):

The *peak* of the `tri` signal is at the point where the *argument* of `tri` (that thingy inside the parentheses following `tri`) equals $0$. The
*base* of the `tri` signal extends from the point where the argument equals
$-\frac 12$ to the point where the argument equals $+\frac 12$ (or $-1$ to $+1$ depending on what you are calling `tri`).  Thus, 
`tri`$\left(\frac{t-t_0}{T}\right)$ is an isoceles triangle whose *apex*
is at the point $(t_0,1)$ and whose base extends from $t_0-\frac{T}{2}$
to $t_0+\frac{T}{2}$ (or from $t_0-T$ to $t_0+T$ for the other
interpretation of `tri`).